# Move wordpress files from one pc to another pc contents showing error

Tags: migration, localhost

Good day!

I am creating a wordpress page in our school as an activity, I wanted to continue everything in my home so I backed-up the database from phpmyadmin and the wordpress folder from htdocs. After heading back home, I copied the wordpress folder to my pc which was from my school then imported the database from the one I have from school to my pc at home. After installing andsetting everything just like the settings from my school, all of the contents went nuts. The design was a total mess.

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I noticed in my database that the plugins and theme table points still to the localhost at school and not it my pc. How do I change this directory path? I thought editing the wp_options would do the trick but still the problem persist. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the prefix of the table?

Comment: Did you change the Wordpress URL and Site URL in Settings/
General? Those are needed to build links to e.g. CSS files. If those aren't found the design will be messed up indeed.

Comment: All I did was update wp_options, wp_comments, wp_posts and wp_postmeta using a query.

Comment: @Jos Yes I have changed the WP URL and SITE URL in wp_options table